# How to validate alerts in Atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I created an alerts in MongoDB Atlas. Now I want to validate them whether they are sending the notifications if they hit the threshold. What is the better way to forcibly reproduce an alert and send a notification ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alert with a metric that you can easily exceed (like # of connections) and verify that the notification is sent.

As far as verifying that a particular metric will send you the alert, you'd probably need to come up with a way to exceed that metric. Which I imagine would be easier if you lowered the threshold for testing purposes.